# R - shortcut for date and breakline with # -----

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

I inadvertently press a shortcut and a really nice sort of *break line* appeard with the date.

It look something like

```
# 23 Jun 2010 --------------------
```

Does someone have an idea of the shortcut in question ??

(I work on an mac!)

In RStudio !

Comment: R-Studio? Ctrl-Shift-R inserts a comment, but not a date

Comment: In my case it directly inserted a date !

Comment: who downvoted this? this is a totally valid question

Comment: @hedgedandlevered - yes I don't know why someone downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you typed `ts`.
To disable or change this, go to tools, global options, code, then at the bottom "edit snippets" then scroll down to the bottom.

Further explanation:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets?version=0.99.441&mode=desktop

Comment: On my system (win81_64, RStudio-0.99.442), it's `ts<Tab><Enter>` or `ts<Tab><Tab>`. Slick indeed.

Comment: haha
do you have the most recent (beta?) version of Rstudio? as @r2evans said, you might have to hit tab or tab enter. shift+tab works too without bringing up the autocomplete menu. I'd recommend checking out snippets, if for nothing else than making something like `tcb` a try catch block with a browser and print out of an error message built in. Pretty convenient.